# How to make a parameter in a function common to both trees?

Tags: c++, oop, c++14

How can I combine these **findNode** functions into one?

```
void CommandsTreeHandler::findNode(CommandsTree * inOutTree)
void DataRefsTreeHandler::findNode(DataRefsTree* inOutTree)
```

```
class CommandsTree : public DataTree<XPLMCommandRef, CommandsTree, STreeHolderSet<CommandsTree, CommandsTreeComparator>>
class DataRefsTree : public DataTree<AbstractDataRef*, DataRefsTree, STreeHolderSet<DataRefsTree, DataRefsTreeComparator>>
```

```
 template <typename Data, typename T, typename Holder = STreeHolderVector<T>> class DataTree : public STree<T, Holder>
```

```
template <typename T, typename Holder = STreeHolderVector<T>> class STree
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only calling functions from STree, you can just create a free standing function `void findNode(STree* inOutTree)`. However, if you're not, look below:

If `CommandsTreeHandler` and `DataRefsTreeHandler` use the same "interface" in findNode (as in, functions are all called with the same parameter orders and types),  then you can just make a template. If you have C++17, you can make specializations on the types if necessary.

```
#include <type_traits>

// This should be a global function outside of both CommandsTreeHandler and DataRefsTreeHandler
template<typename Tree_t>
void findNode(Tree_t* inOutTree) {
   using CTH = CommandsTreeHandler;
   using DRTH = DataRefsTreeHandler;

   // Ensure either a CTH or DRTH is passed in
   static_assert(std::is_same<Tree_t, CTH>::value || std::is_same<Tree_t, DRTH>::value);

   ... // Calls here should be compatible with both CTH and DRTH

   // However, inline specialization like below requires C++17 or greater
   if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Tree_t, CTH>)
       ... // Do something different for CTH
   else
       ... // Do something different for DRTH
}
```

If you have C++20, you can do:

```
#include <concepts>

using CTH = CommandsTreeHandler;
using DRTH = DataRefsTreeHandler;

template<typename Tree_t>
requires (std::same_as<CTH> || std::same_as<DRTH>)
void findNode(Tree_t* inOutTree) {
    ... // Calls here should be compatible with both CTH and DRTH

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Tree_t, CTH>)
        ... // Do something different for CTH
    else
        ... // Do something different for DRTH
}
```

Sadly, without C++17, you'll have to use two separate functions if you want any specialization anyways and you will be back to where you started. I suggest you see if you can refactor the tree code and give it a common "tree interface"

Comment: I need calling functions from DataTree, I try  `template <typename Data, typename T, typename Holder> void DataBaseTreeHandler::findNode(DataTree<Data, T, Holder>* inOutTree)` **but I got**
Error C2664 'std::pair<std::size_t,sasl::DataRefsTree *>::pair(std::pair<std::size_t,sasl::DataRefsTree *> &&)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'sasl::DataTree<sasl::AbstractDataRef *,sasl::DataRefsTree,sasl::STreeHolderSet<sasl::DataRefsTree,sasl::DataRefsTreeComparator>> *' to 'sasl::DataRefsTree *const &' (compiling source file

Comment: You didn't even try what I put?